# Array with Resize() vs List

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, list

In C#, Internally List encapsulate Array.In both data structure we can access the element using index.
`List<T>` equals `Array[T]` and support adding/removing items.

If the capacity of the list is full then, internally new array with size equals to 2 * capacity will be created and all element are moved to new array. Is this true?

If true,then size of the array and list are increased dynamically.
What are the benefits of using `List<T>` over `Array[T]` with `Array.Resize(ref myArray, 2*size);`?

Comment: Do you mean "what is the benefit of using `List<T>` rather than building my own implementation of `List<T>`?" Time.

Comment: Depends on the workload. List can never be faster than a manual implementation.

Comment: This question is bordering on unclear or too broad. Yes, it is true that when you fill up the internal array kept by the list a new one with bigger size is created. I don't think it is documented that it will be twice the size though, but perhaps. Other than that, the benefit of the list is that it can grow, as such since you already know this, can you clarify what exactly you're looking for in an answer here?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't think there is an official spec, but microsoft reference implementation behaves like that.

Comment: Time to link to the obligatory Eric Lippert blog on performance... http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: By the way, the question does not make sense, because they are semantically different, so performance comparison does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of variables here, a good rule of thumb would be, if the array will remain at its current size for a long period of time an Array may be more appropriate.  However, in most scenarios, where the collection is transient, a list will perform better since an array has to find contiguous space in memory for its creation.  I would say though the best approach with any sort of performance optimization is to measure and optimize where you actually find an issue.  Premature optimization is often a waste of time.

Comment: By viewing [the source code of List<T>](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs), one can see that it uses an array internaly, which is not being resized. When needed, the old array is being copied into a new, bigger array which replaces the old one. So, I'm curious: Is "list vs array" actually "`Array.Resize()` vs `Array::CopyTo()` and replace" ? If yes, what result does this comparison yield?